# regexp to find locale in URL

Tags: php, regex

I'm doing regular expression to parse url and find locale on my website. What I did is this code:

```
<?php

$app_conf = require_once __DIR__ . '/../config/app.php';

function extract_lang($avail)
{
    $uri_lang = [];
    if (preg_match('/^(\/)+([a-z]{2})(\/+.*)?/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $uri_lang)) {
        if (in_array($uri_lang[2], $avail)) {
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = isset($uri_lang[3]) ? $uri_lang[3] : "/";
            $_SERVER['HTTP_LANG'] = $uri_lang[2];
        }
    }
}

if ($app_conf['extract_from_uri']) {
    extract_lang($app_conf['locales']);
}
```

It's working most of the time, but it has bug. If my given url starts with 'en' - it thinks its a locale and crashes my application's logic. Example route that causes bug:

```
https://m2.test/environmental_projects
```

I need to somehow update my regular expression and I'm struggling with it, please help me.
In locales config I have array

```
'locales' => ['en', 'ru']
```

Okay route should look like

```
https://m2.test/en/environmental_projects
```

Comment: What does the url with the `en` or `ru` look like? The pattern currently matches 1 or more times a forward slash, then 2 times a char a-z, followed by an optional part than matches 1+ times a forward slash and optionally any char. As the last part is optional, there is nothing to prevent the 2 char a-z from matching.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Updated my question with example of how route should look like.

Comment: Like `^/([a-z]{2})(/.*)?$`  https://regex101.com/r/K4GwGP/1 `if (preg_match('~^/([a-z]{2})(/.*)?$~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $uri_lang)) {`

Comment: @Thefourthbird well, it looks like what I need, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match a single forward slash, capture in the first group 2 chars a-z and then make group 2 optional matching a forward slash and any char except a newline ending with an anchor `$`

N**ote** that now there are 2 capturing groups instead of 3, and if you change the [delimiter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) to a char other than `/` like for example `~`, you don't have to escape the forward slash.

```
^/([a-z]{2})(/.*)?$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K4GwGP/1/)

For example

```
if (preg_match('~^/([a-z]{2})(/.*)?$~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $uri_lang)) {
```